# Content jumping after animation in chrome browser in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, animate.css, wow.js

I am currently trying to add animations to various elements of this page using 'Animate.css' and 'Wow.js' jQuery plugin.

When I am viewing this page on a mobile browser, especially on chrome then after scrolling to a section the animation runs but after that the content of the page jumps to other location. This issue is not happening in firefox browser in mobile, just the animation is not working that much smoothly.

Here is the link to the page.

[wow effect test](https://lalitpal.com/wow11/)

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you find a solution ?